# I get http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error in my NextJs application using google signin. Why?

Tags: reactjs, next-auth

Here is my [...nextauth].js file ...

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Providers from "next-auth/providers";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Providers.Google({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
});
```

Here is my header component where I want to pass the signin function...

```
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/client";

function Header() {
    return(
     <div onClick={signIn}>
          <p>Sign In</p>
     </div>
    )
```

When I click on it, it returns a 404 response yet I am supposed to see this below:

[image: signIn with google next js interface]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I got the blunder. It was in my file naming. It is supposed to be **pages/api/auth** not *pages/api/Auth*. Fix that and it will work. This is for anyone else who will find themselves in this small bug.

Comment: thank you! i had similar issue I had ` [...nextauth].ts` there was leading whitespace. i removed that and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you should logout and try again , I clear session and cookies and resolved problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks @Ahmad for your insights.